# Regarding OOPs Concept

Tags: c#, oop

There are two classes in following way.

```
Class A { int i; } 
Class B : A { int j; }
```

How can I initialize i=1 and j=2 in a single command or in optimized way?

Comment: What are you trying to do? if you want each instance of class A the  value of variable i be 1, then you could just do this at the definition of i. Like `class A{ int i = 1; }`

Comment: Have you looked at constructors?

Comment: Thanks. I had replied with Constructor option but Interviewer expecting some thing else!

Comment: Answer to this question can be easily acquired by a simple study.

Comment: Other than changing these classes, you can't. Since no privacy modifier has been specified, the fields are private by default and thus only settable from inside the class(es) in question. If you make them public you can use initializer syntax. Since this is apparently an interview question it probably has artificial limitations and thus falls prey to not being "constructive practical problems" that are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those fields were public (or internal):

```
class A { public int i; } 
class B : A { public int j; }
```

you could use initializer like this:

```
var b = new B() { i = 1, j = 2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the context of an interview, the expected one-line answer was probably:

```
var b = new B { i = 1, j = 2 };
```

Do note it's not *better optimized* than just creating a new instance then affecting a value to some public field/properties.

Comment: Private fields though, but this is probably more what the interviewer expected.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Fair assumption, but as the OP's code is actually broken (`Class` instead of `class`) it's hard to tell.

Comment: Good point. It is most likely paraphrased from memory, for all we know the fields were actually public in the actual interview question.